# How do I authenticate an Expo React Native app using PKCE and allow token refresh?

Tags: react-native, expo, openid-connect

I feel like I'm missing a trick here. We have a managed Expo app and we're trying to authenticate the user against an OIDC identity provider (in our case it's Cognito).

It seems to two options we have are either `expo-auth-session` or `expo-app-auth`.

- It seems that `expo-auth-session` will support a PKCE flow, but doesn't have a mechanism for refreshing the token.
- `expo-app-auth`, on the other hand, does have a mechanism for refreshing the token but doesn't seem to support a PKCE flow.

I don't want to increase the token timeout because that's a security risk.
I also don't want to use an implicit flow because that's also a security risk.

There is an open PR against AuthSession to add refresh token support, but the fact that the library has been out for this long without it makes me wonder if I'm missing something.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

AppAuth supports both PKCE and refresh tokens, and is the most recommended option from a security viewpoint, but is tricky to implement. In React Native there is an [AppAuth Bridge](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth), though you would have more options with native mobile tech.

I have some code samples and blog posts that highlight AppAuth usage. Steps 8-10 of each post demonstrate PKCE and steps 15-16 demonstrate token refresh:

- [iOS Sample in SwiftUI](https://authguidance.com/2020/02/22/how-to-run-the-ios-code-sample/)
- [Android Sample in Kotlin](https://authguidance.com/2019/09/29/basicandroidapp-execution/)

Comment: Thanks for that Gary. We're actually using a managed Expo app, and using `react-native-app-auth` would require us to eject (which I'm unwilling to do at this stage). Therefore we can only use the two Expo provided components. I actually have a temporary solution which works for the time being, but it's not very generally applicable (as it involves a fork of an Expo PR). Once I've got a more general solution in place I'll update this question with it!

Comment: @ashward are you able to give anymore details as I can't find the PR